# Run installed node program from within a shell script

Tags: node.js, bash, nvm

I have used nvm to setup a specific node version,

```
nvm install 9.11.1
```

I have a nodejs program built and installed:

```
npm install -g osmlint
```

This is the full path of the newly minted executable:

```
which osmlint
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/bin/osmlint
```

I run it with the following command:

```
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/bin/osmlint crossingbuildings --bbox="[72.9,18.8,73,18.9]" --zoom=12 india.mbtiles > test.txt
```

And it works fine.

I've put the same in a bash shell script. (say, `run1.sh`). But when I run the shell script, it errors out.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/osmlint/node_modules/@mapbox/tile-reduce/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v72-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:
- /root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/osmlint/node_modules/@mapbox/tile-reduce/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
- /root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/osmlint/node_modules/@mapbox/tile-reduce/node_modules/@mapbox/mbtiles/lib/mbtiles.js
- /root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/osmlint/node_modules/@mapbox/tile-reduce/src/index.js
- /root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/osmlint/validators/crossingBuildings/index.js
- /root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/osmlint/cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/osmlint/node_modules/@mapbox/tile-reduce/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/osmlint/node_modules/@mapbox/tile-reduce/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js',
    '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/osmlint/node_modules/@mapbox/tile-reduce/node_modules/@mapbox/mbtiles/lib/mbtiles.js',
    '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/osmlint/node_modules/@mapbox/tile-reduce/src/index.js',
    '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/osmlint/validators/crossingBuildings/index.js',
    '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/lib/node_modules/osmlint/cli.js'
  ]
}
```

Apparently the same node environment isn't in effect inside the shell script's bash environment. How do we make this work?

Answer (score 1):

To run the node executable from shell script, we need to set the node environment.

```
nvm use 9.11.1
```

But even `nvm` is unknown to the bash environment of the shell script. So, need to set that up.

```
source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Combined commands:

```
# required : initialize nvm, then make it set the current node version to v9.11.1
source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm use 9.11.1
# run osmlint. # mention full path of executable.
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/bin/osmlint crossingbuildings --bbox="[72.9,18.8,73,18.9]" --zoom=12 india.mbtiles > test.txt
```

..and that worked. Sharing this in case others like me get stuck with having to run a node program from inside a shell script.